# How to get sObject field value

Tags: apex, dynamic-binding, dynamic-apex

This question is related to more or less that I have asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172857/how-to-bind-apexinputfield-using-dynamic-sobject)

My question is, how to get the field value from sObject to little demo you here.

Here is my vfp:

```
<apex:page controller="dynamicApexController" >
    <apex:form id="theFrm">
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Dynamic" id="pb1"   > 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="some title" columns="1"> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!mySobject['field_1__c']}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!mySobject['field_2__c']}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save"  action="{!saveMe}" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class dynamicApexController 
{
    public SObject mySobject {get; set;}
    public Id sObjectId {get;set;}
    public String objectName {get;set;} 

    public dynamicApexController()
    { 
        sObjectId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  

        //building object and fields:

        objectName = sObjectId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName(); 
        Set<String> setFields = new Set<String>();        
        DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = sObjectId.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objSchema.fields.getMap();
        for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet())
        {
            SObjectField sfield = fieldMap.get(fieldName);
            schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
            String field = dfield.getName(); 
            setFields.add(field);
        }
        String soqlQuery ='SELECT ';
        for(String sReqField : setFields) {            
            soqlQuery +=  sReqField + ','; 
        }
        soqlQuery = soqlQuery.removeEnd(',');
        soqlQuery += '  FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Id =  \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(sObjectId) + '\'';

        mySobject = Database.query(soqlQuery);

    }

    //save 
    public PageReference saveMe()
    {
       string f1 = mySobject.get('field_1__c');
       string f2 = mySobject.get('field_2__c');

       //once you get the value of f1, f2 then upsert to that sobject.

       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the value at all? Why not just `update mySobject`?

Comment: the reason is that those two fields are optional so i want to check if there is any value in it, before I update the object

Comment: But *why*? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: save whatever the user entered in those fields, if the user left blank then will get prompt to enter

Comment: Just make the `<apex:inputField>` tags required then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to enforce a value in these fields before you save, just set the attribute `required="true"` on your `<apex:inputField>` tags.

```
<apex:inputField required="true" value="{!record['Field1__c']}" />
<apex:inputField required="true" value="{!record['Field2__c']}" />
```

---

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, you should be able to check if the values are null in your controller as follows:

```
if (null == record.get('Field1__c'))
{
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Field 1 Must be populated'
    ));
    return null;
}
if (null == record.get('Field2__c'))
{
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Field 2 Must be populated'
    ));
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes I could easily add the required attribute but in my case I have some custom business logic that I need to implement for that reason I need to check the value before I update the object.

Comment: @NickKahn See my update. Note that you didn't give your `<apex:pageMessages>` tag an `id` attribute, so you cannot `rerender` it.